# Customize function Variation product in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a project in wordpress and I am using woocommerce.
I have 3 attributes for each product and some variation. Look like this:

[image: Example]

Now is mandatory to choose at least 1 variation for each attribute in order to get a price.

I wonder if its possible to get out a price from a first choice so I dont need to be forced to select the second and third attribute.
In my case I would like to get a 25 euro price if I select "digital".
So in some way "hide" or obfuscate all the other choices when "digital" is selected.

I found this plugin: "Simple linked variations for WooCommerce". but this just hide 1 variation based on one attribute and it does not show the price either.

I guess there must be something in the code that show the price ONLY if all 3 attributes are selected. And can hide/obfuscade another attribute (or give value 0).... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using product add-ons" instead of variations.
https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/

This extension lets you create various add-ons for a product, and you can set up conditions like the one I describe.